# How can I tell my database that some changes are made by hibernate and not by other application?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I'm new in working with hibernate and I've got this isue.
I work with Oracle db and Hibernate+Maven+Netbeans. My purpose is to be able to do changes in my database only with my authorized app. Making changes from SQL console or others programs should not be possible. For this I made a table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA(
   name  char(30),
   day   integer,
   month integer,
   year  integer );
```

And a trigger like this which restricts any access on my database:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_block
     BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON data
    BEGIN
       IF  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'hh24')) < 12
           OR TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'hh24')) >= 12
            OR TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'dy') in ('sun','sat') THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, 'changes can not be made');
    END IF;
   END;
```

And this is my HibernateUtil.java :

```
 package com.scooby.util;

    import com.scooby.DATA;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
                                .addAnnotatedClass(DATA.class).buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

  }
```

I heard something about ORACLE contexts and something about the session in hibernate. Can someone explain me?

Comment: There is no good way to do this. You can restrict access by network address and username/password. Other than that, Oracle cannot tell what client application you are using, especially if that client is actively trying to pretend to be something else (there is an "application name", but the client can set that to whatever it feels like). So you'll have to lock down the password and/or network.

Comment: So you are saying I can restrict access by network address for all apps, except my authorized one?

Comment: That is a common approach, yes. Three-tier architecture. No one gets to talk to the DB directly, except for the approved app (which runs on a host that you control).

Comment: PostgreSQL for example default locks down the app so it can only be accessed by localhost. So, if there are multiple apps running on same machine, then that's a problem. But if some app from other server is trying to connect to DB, that will fail. I don't know what Oracle does as I have never used it.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger is likely not a good solution for preventing unauthorized write access. The standard solution would be to **create a new user for your app**, then have the neccessary Oracle privileges granted/revoked to/from all users to ensure that only your application is allowed to write certain tables.

If you are not satisfied with this solution, there is the sys_context [solution](http://psoug.org/reference/sys_context.html), which is definitely **less secure** then the other. It offers much wider range of features for auditing though, but also requires much more work on DB side, plus calling stored procedures from the app as well.